# "from builtins import *" and super() in python2: bad practice?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm trying to backport my Python3 package to Python2. I used `pasteurize` and all works fine. I noticed that it imported a few stuff from `builtins` including `str`, `int` and `super`. I was wondering if importing everything from `builtins` is safe. Yes, I know that in principle [asterisk import is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad) because it clutters the current namespace, doesn't make it clear what's imported and override names you don't intend to. But when it comes to `builtins` in particular isn't it true that all of them are already present as names, are safe to import and shouldn't break anything?

Also, if using `super` from `builtins` in Python2 code is it safe to call it as Python3's `super` with no arguments? Are there edge-cases where it may break with Python2?

```
from builtins import * # is this frowned upon?
from future import standard_library
standard_library.install_aliases()

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # is this always safe in python 2?
```

---

**Edit 1**: Just to clarify, for Python2 `builtins` comes from `future` and is not a built-in module as in Python3.

**Edit 2**: Some people have suggested that calling `super` with no arguments *never* works and that importing from `builtins` makes no difference. Obviously this is wrong.

```
from __future__ import print_function

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x + 1

class Baz(Bar, Foo):
    def __init__(self, x):
        super().__init__(x)

try:
    b = Baz(1)
except TypeError as e:
    # this will only happen in Python 2
    print("Didn't work: {}; trying with builtins.super".format(str(e)))
    from builtins import super
    b = Baz(1) # this now works in Python 2.7 too
print(b.x)
```

Comment: It would be bad from performance standpoint. Only import what you really need.

Comment: @mvp that is simply not true. This will have no effect on performance.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: NOT doing something extra is obviously faster than doing it?

Comment: Can you elaborate @DavisHerring ? Isn't future's `newsuper` supposed to do exactly this: enable argument-less `super` ?

Comment: @AaylaSecura: No, you’re right: I just thought you meant “the built-in `super`”, but you meant exactly what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This super is a reimplementation of the Python 3 super that works, but don't expect to be as efficient as the Python 3 super.

In Python 3 the compiler cheats, and whenever it sees the name `super` referenced in a function, it automatically adds a cell variable called `__class__` to the function. The `super` function makes use of `__class__` to make up for arguments not being passed to it. You can see this in action by doing something like:

```
class X:
    def f(self):
        super
        return __class__

assert X().f() is X
assert X.f.__closure__[0].cell_contents is X
```

`__class__` is defined once (when the function is first compiled)+ and so this lookup that super does is very quick.

`newsuper`, on the other hand needs to drill down through the MRO (and any decorators) each and every time to figure out the type of `self` and the type that the function was defined one. **It seems good for back porting Python 3** (probably why it exists in `future.builtins`). **But that you should otherwise stick to the standard Python 2** `super`**, so people reading your code aren't surprised by this.**

Implementation: (taken from https://github.com/rfk/magicsuper/blob/master/magicsuper/_super.py (as documented by `future.builtins.newsuper`))

```
def super(typ=_SENTINEL, type_or_obj=_SENTINEL, framedepth=1):
    '''Like builtin super(), but capable of magic.
    This acts just like the builtin super() function, but if called
    without any arguments it attempts to infer them at runtime.
    '''
    #  Infer the correct call if used without arguments.
    if typ is _SENTINEL:
        # We'll need to do some frame hacking.
        f = sys._getframe(framedepth)

        try:
            # Get the function's first positional argument.
            type_or_obj = f.f_locals[f.f_code.co_varnames[0]]
        except (IndexError,KeyError,):
            raise RuntimeError('super() used in a function with no args')

        try:
            # Get the MRO so we can crawl it.
            mro = type_or_obj.__mro__
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                mro = type_or_obj.__class__.__mro__
            except AttributeError:
                raise RuntimeError('super() used with a non-newstyle class')

        #   A ``for...else`` block?  Yes!  It's odd, but useful.
        #   If unfamiliar with for...else, see:
        #
        #       http://psung.blogspot.com/2007/12/for-else-in-python.html
        for typ in mro:
            #  Find the class that owns the currently-executing method.
            for meth in typ.__dict__.itervalues():
                # Drill down through any wrappers to the underlying func.
                # This handles e.g. classmethod() and staticmethod().
                try:
                    while not isinstance(meth,FunctionType):
                        try:
                            meth = meth.__func__
                        except AttributeError:
                            meth = meth.__get__(type_or_obj)
                except (AttributeError, TypeError):
                    continue
                if meth.func_code is f.f_code:
                    break   # Aha!  Found you.
            else:
                continue    #  Not found! Move onto the next class in MRO.
            break    #  Found! Break out of the search loop.
        else:
            raise RuntimeError('super() called outside a method')

    #  Dispatch to builtin super().
    if type_or_obj is not _SENTINEL:
        return _builtin_super(typ,type_or_obj)
return _builtin_super(typ)
```

Comment: There will be (weird) cases where such a faux `super` will have different behavior, like monkeypatching a class from another class.  Probably not a problem, but worth remembering.